# indexing not reliable on WindowCollection

Tags: ruby, watir

I have upgraded to recent WATIR(7.0.0.beta5) and when I am executing the following line

```
@browser.windows.last.use
```

I am getting this error

```
"indexing not reliable on WindowCollection"
```

This was working fine in my previous WATIR version(6.19.1). What is the issue?

Another question is, It looks like there are plenty of changes of capabilities. Do I have to set `page_load_timeout` and `read_timeout` separately now? and also I have read `open_timeout`, I don't know what it is for, Can someone help me understand what it is?

Comment: I added an answer to your main question. You should split your second question into another question since it's quite different and will likely need someone else to answer it.

Comment: Sure I will do. I have added a comment in your answer. Accessing using INDEX is the only way for me. I explained in the answer

Comment: You can keep up with changes on our blog: http://watir.com/watir-6-18/#browser-windows
Also, the documentation has been updated on our site: https://watir.com/guides/windows/

Comment: @titusfortner You wrote in your article "Locating by index is no longer supported"But I have been handling windows for a long time using index and it works perfectly for me in the order it was opened in chrome. And also, I have created a framework where I am giving the facility to the user to decide which window to be interacted using index, that's easy for them so far. In our application 3 to 4 windows will be opened. And also my question is to why to close the facility rather than simply allowing it to be. People those wants to use using index, let them use it, what you say?

Comment: This isn't that hard to understand. Per the spec (https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) "The order in which the window handles are returned is arbitrary." This is about the "Principle of Least Surprise". #index didn't always do what people expected, so we changed the Watir API to prefer methods that ensure users always get the behavior they expect.

Comment: @titusfortner I get it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drivers are not guaranteed to always return windows in the same order, so it has been decided to deprecate accessing windows based on their index (ie position in the Array of windows). You have a couple of options.

**Working with 2 windows**

If you are only working with 2 windows (probably most cases), the recommendation is to use 2 new methods:

```
# Switch to the second window that was opened
browser.switch_window 

# Return to the first window
browser.original_window
```

**Working with 3+ windows**

The best approach would be to locate the window you want based on known properties:

```
# By url
browser.window(url: /closeable\.html/).use

# By title
browser.window(title: 'closeable window').use

# By an element in the window (new)
browser.window(element: browser.a(id: 'close')).use
```

**(Not Recommended) By index**

This is not recommended, but if you insist on using index, you can cheat by forcing the WindowsCollection to an Array:

```
browser.windows.each.to_a.last
```

Comment: I have created a framework in which people will decide using the index of which window to access. They won't be writing ruby code, they just mention the action as switch_to_new_window and in data column, they will simply give the number of which window to be accessed.So they don't have to know the title or other detail you mentioned. So your last solution is the only way. Thanks for the answer. But I request you give a way to access the window using index again. That's what easy for us. We are opening 4 to 5 windows.  And your solution works for me. I used `browser.windows.to_enum.to_a.last` .

Comment: Given the possible inconsistency of using index, it's preferred to steer people away from it (ie not easily available). As there is a very simple workaround, is there really a benefit of re-adding the old behaviour?